# javaScript closures. Undefined value as input stops script. Sometimes

Tags: javascript, closures, undefined, referenceerror

Playing with javascript closures I end up with this question I cannot reach to explain.

```
(function() {
    console.log("Inside closure"); //does not work
}(foo));
```

It does not work because foo is undefined. referenceError

But if prior I set `var foo = undefined;` it works (tested on Chrome and ff).

It is not the same to be undefined that to be set to undefined?

[example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0nj7fk1/)

Comment: Yes, referencing an identifier which doesn't exist is a reference error. What is your question, exactly?

Comment: see this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/g0nj7fk1/)
If I set  `var identifier = undefined;`   it doesn´throw a reference error

Comment: Dude. One thing is one var doesn't exists and it is undefined, other is to exist and it's set to undefined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javaScript, 'undefined' is one of the primitive data types. It represents the type of an object.

```
var a = undefined;
var b;

console.log((typeof(a)));
console.log((typeOf(b)));
```

The output will be undefined for both the cases.

If you don't declare a variable at all and try to access it, the error thrown will be the following. I tried to access c which is not declared at all.
Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined(…)

Answer (score 0):

If the question is:

> But what if somebody uses the the common jQuery wrapper and has the jQuery script not working yet?

Then you will still get a reference error if the jQuery identifier is not in the global scope because it is trying to find the reference to jQuery but it will not exist.

the undefined keyword is passed in the closure so that if undefined is assigned a value, it will not mess with your code. For example:

```
var undefined = 123
if(undefined){
    console.log("pass")
}
```

this code will pass. If you Pass through undefined but leave out the parameter when you invoke it, undefined will have not a value assigned to it. It wont be looking for a reference as you haven't assigned the parameter For example :

```
(function(undefined){
// undefined will be undefined. 
}())
```

I've done a quick example here for you :  https://jsfiddle.net/gn7h3641/

TLDR : if your asking JavaScript for the value of a variable that doesn't exist(not been defined with var), it will explode because it has not got a reference to find the value yet which is different to checking if something is undefined in a 'if(test === undefined)'

Answer (score 0):

Having a variable whose value is undefined is not the same as having no variable with that name.

In ECMAScript, identifiers are resolved according to [Identifier Resolution](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3.1), which returns a reference given by [GetIdentifierReference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.2.1).

In case the variable doesn't exist, the base value of that reference will be undefined, otherwise it will be an environment record.

When [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1) gets the value of that reference, it will check [IsUnresolvableReference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7). If the base value is undefined, it will return false, and GetValue will throw a ReferenceError exception.

If the variable exists (even if its value is undefined), GetValue will return its value.

If you are not sure whether some variable exists, you can use [the `typeof` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3), which returns `"undefined"` for unresolvable references instead of throwing.